# How properly synchronous resolve list of promises in typescript / javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I have list of promises what obtain data from database, modify it and save,
some promises can work with same data, to exclude possible conflicts, I decide execute promise synchronous, I write next function, but I suspect that it can be done more simply and the rule.

Typescript

```
async function syncPromises<T>(arr: (() => Promise<T>)[]) {
  const result : T[] = [];

  for(const fn of arr) {
    result.push(await fn());
  }

  return result;
}
```

JavaScript

```
async function syncPromises(arr) {
  const result = [];

  for(const fn of arr) {
    result.push(await fn());
  }

  return result;
}
```

Currently I use similar code for call function

```
const ids = [ 3, 5 ];
syncPromises(ids.map(id => () => someLogicWhatNeedExecSync(id)));
```

I think this can be more simple

Comment: Promises are not "executed". What you have in your `arr` are *functions* that return promises, and you can run them sequentially. You cannot do that with an array of promises, the only thing you can do with a promise is to wait for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of taking an array of functions, take an array of values and a single function to apply to them - basically `map`:

```
async function sequentialMap<V, R>(arr: V[], fn: (v: V) => Promise<R>): Promise<R[]> {
  const result : R[] = [];
  for (const value of arr) {
    result.push(await fn(value));
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can use it as

```
const ids = [ 3, 5 ];
sequentialMap(ids, someLogicWhatNeedExecSync);
```

Comment: In my typescript version require use   (e: V) => Promise<R> instead V => Promise<R>

Comment: @HardCoreQual Right. I still struggle with the requirement for naming parameters in type declarations…

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and TypeScript have some subtleties when it comes to looping over functions you want to await.

This pages explains the options and differences very well: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-foreach-in-javascript/

If you want all promises to be resolved before returning, then you can't use a for-loop but should rather use `arr.map()` or `arr.reduce()`

In your case where you want to return an array, the easiest is probably to use a `arr.map()` as it returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely agree with the approach mentioned by @Bergi.
Another way can be to use `Promise.all()`

```
function asyncTimeoutFunction(id){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(id),1000);
    })
}

const ids = [ 3, 5, 2 ];
const functions = ids.map((id)=>{
    return asyncTimeoutFunction(id);
});

Promise.all(functions).then(console.log);
```

Just replace your Asynchronous function with asyncTimeoutFunction.

Comment: I want await resolve promise for first element, start next promise, await resolve, start next ...   , your code start all promises simultan

Comment: Ok. Since the function is same then I thought simultaneous resolution would be better. Anyway as per your use case, bergi’s answer would be apt.